# How I use the modals bootstrap automatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Hei, I want know how put in my application the [bootstrap modals](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals), but I need it launch them automatically, the objective is show a error message... I throw them on the catch block in ASP .NET(this I can do) ;D 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript method, passing the script: `$('#myModal').modal('show')`. If you are in a partial postback, you should use the RegisterClientScriptBlock instead.

[]s

Comment: ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(),"Javascript","script",true);   <- I use this and run Thanks Friend!

Answer (score 1):

You might have to include some Javascript on the page: if there's an error, show the modal through the Javscript API, as shown in [the docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals).

```
if (error) {
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
}
```